Primevue Listbox with virtualscroller hides all items
I have Primevue listbox with 20+ items which gets too long for my page.
Following the example on https://primevue.org/listbox/#virtualscroll I added :virtualScrollerOptions="{ itemSize: 38}", but then the entire listbox, except for the filter box, disappears
I have a Primevue Listbox set up as follows
My Primevue version is 3.44.0
<Listbox
    v-model="state.foo"
    :options="foo"
    optionLabel="title"
    optionValue="id"
    multiple
    filter
></Listbox>

which results in
Listbox with items shown
Because this list can get rather long, I want to implement the VirtualScroller, as described here https://primevue.org/listbox/#virtualscroll
However, when I follow the example the entire list disappears
<Listbox
    v-model="state.foo"
    :virtualScrollerOptions="{ itemSize: 38 }"
    :options="foo"
    optionLabel="title"
    optionValue="id"
    multiple
    filter
></Listbox>

Listbox with items gone
Am I missing anything to make this work properly?
